# How to generate a list of request.POST in Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views

I have the following code in views.py:

```
def valores(request):
    global peso_unitario, preco_unitario
    peso_unitario=[]
    preco_unitario=[]

    N=a
    print('N='+str(N))

    for i in range(N):
        peso_u = request.POST['peso_u']
        preco_u = request.POST['preco_u']

        if peso_u.isdigit() and preco_u.isdigit():
            c = int(peso_u)
            d = int(preco_u)
            peso_unitario.append(c)
            preco_unitario.append(d)
            print(a)
            if i==N-1:
                return render(request, 'pacote.html', {'peso_unitario': peso_unitario, 'preco_unitario': preco_unitario})
        else:
            res = 'Apenas numero.'
            return render(request, 'pacote.html', {'res': res})
```

One step before, where we filled a text field with a number N. Now, I'd like to generate N text fields to be filled by the user, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: can you please explain more clearly what you want to do?

Comment: Also I see you are using global variables, that's not advisable. Unless you are going to have just a single server running and just a single user you will have cases of data being missing across requests or other users data being shared with the current user.

Comment: @DivyaPrakash from what I understand he want to provide form functionality... Generally he could generate fields on the fly on the init method on custom form, or add custom fields to template rendered by `render_to_string` method.

Comment: I support formset answer. NEVER use request.POST directly, except for passing it to form, formset or serializer, it's huge anti-pattern that easily leads to broken data you might find much later

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `formset` to generate `N` forms dynamically. You can refer to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/formsets/#formsets) to see how to implement one.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use globals. You need to store the previously retrieved number N somewhere. Maybe in the user's session. Maybe pass it to this view as a querystring, and have a default value or redirect back to the form which should have obtained it if its missing.

Anyway, having obtained that N, you can build the form with N similar forms dynamically. (As mentioned by others, another way is to use a formset).

```
class Baseform( forms.Form):
   ...
   # everything apart from the variable  fields

fields = {}
for n in range(N):
     fields[ f'form_{n}'] = forms.Charfield( # or whatever
         label = f'form{n}', ... # other form args
     )

My_Dynamic_Form = type(
    'My_Dynamic_Form',  (BaseForm, ), fields
)
```

Instantiate, check as usual, process the variable fields:

```
form = My_Dynamic_Form( ...)
if form.is_valid():
    # your variable data will be in form.cleaned_data['form_0'] upwards.
    # maybe
    for n in range(1000):
        key = f'form_{n}'
        if not (key in form.cleaned_data):
            break
        val = form.cleaned_data.get(key)
        # do whatever with val
```

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate **all** posted data using `request.POST.items()` example:

```
for key, value in request.POST.items():
    print(f"{key}: {value}")
```

**Output:**

> name: momo
>
>  lastname: titi